# Function signature returning abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, language-lawyer, signature

Consider some abstract class `A`:

```
class A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

Suppose I wish to declare a function signature type returning this class:

```
using Type = A();
```

Given this code, `gcc-4.8.2` failes with error

```
error: ‘type name’ declared as function returning an abstract class type
```

`clang-3.3` compiles this nicely.

I tried to google this issue, but failed to find anything usefull. Is this code standard-compliant? If not, what is the reasoning behind forbidding declaring such signature type? I don't see any problems in just a declaration.

*Disclaimer*: I am **NOT** going to create instances of this type, I'm just interested in declaring a signature described.

For those interested in usefullness of such a declaration: I have some factory container that uses a signature like `Interface(Arguments...)` when adding new factories to learn something about the new factory; the actual returned type is determined based on a separate traits class, parametrised by `Interface`.

Obviously, I can just separate `Interface` from signature, but it won't look *that* nice :(

Comment: `I don't see any problems in just a declaration.` OK. But can you see any use for such declaration?

Comment: @user2079303 included my usecase in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this code standard-compliant?

No. According to C++11 [class.abstract]/3, "An abstract class shall not be used as a parameter type, as a **function return type**, or as the type of an explicit conversion."

> If not, what is the reasoning behind forbidding declaring such signature type?

A function of that signature can't exist, since it would have to create an object of an abstract class type when it returns.

> I don't see any problems in just a declaration.

Indeed, just a declaration would be harmless. But it would also be somewhat useless; it wouldn't refer to any type that can exist.

For your use-case, you could use a reference or pointer as the return type.

Comment: I included a usecase I faced in the question.

Comment: The fact that such a function cannot exist does not forbid using this type in some template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object of an abstract class by definition. Thus a function returning an abstract object just does not make sense. If you still want to return `A` in some way, you have to return a pointer (that in fact will have to point to an object of a concrete subclass).

Comment: I *do not want* to create an object of type `A` or return it from a function. I only want to *declare a signature* returning this type.

Comment: @lisyarus Hopefully you will return a *pointer* or *reference* to your base class, instead of by value, or you will [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) instances of derived classes.

Comment: would be intersting to know why I got a down vote on this ... (I gave worse answers without downvotes ;))

Comment: @tobi303 I asked about *declaring a type of a function signature*. Neither about an actual function with this signature, nor about creating an object of an abstract class. So, I think that this answer has nothing to do with the question.